# Centre nav in landscape view on device

Tags: android, ios, css, responsive-design

Is there a way that I can centralise the nav bar and have it sit under the logo when in landscape (480px) and also portrait view (320px)?

At the moment when in portrait view the nav is pretty much centered under the logo, but when I turn the phone to landscape the nav aligns left.

Here's a link to the website: http://scoundrelscomedyclub.co.uk.carbon.3dpixel.net/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 585px) {
    #mainNav {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 302px;
    }
}
```

I centered it by setting a fixed width. Now `margin: 0 auto` can center it.